# Facebook Native Ads API, show video only

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x, facebook-audience-network

I'm using Facebook Audience Native Ads in my android app and I want to show only video ads to my users. Is there a way to detect that the loaded NativeAd will contain video advertising and not just image ?

Comment: I am facing same issue ,Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can check the extension of the coverView with getAdCoverImage().getUrl()